# Convention for primary app deployment dir structure on a Unix-like app server

Tags: directory-structure

The client I'm working for deploys their application to a directory they created at the root level.  While acknowledging it is a matter of local preference, I am unsure if this is in accordance with the generally accepted standard how to distribute an application's components across a Unix-like system.  E.g. normally, I would put the binaries for my deployed app to `/opt`, conf files in `/etc`, logs under `/var` etc.  But then again, this is the primary application the server is used for so it isn't exactly equivalent to untaring some 3rd party software into `/opt`.

Still, personally, I would prefer not to add any dirs at the root level, i.e. would keep that level sort of sacred out of respect for the original Unix file hierarchy.  I wanted to ask whether this is common and what are some ramifications of this approach.

Answer (score 3):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) defines where particular files go. As an administrator of a server, you can choose to place files wherever you want. The primary ramification is when "the next guy" takes over and has to figure out the non-standard locations.